# interfere with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's schedule

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I used `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduledAtFixedRate` to schedule some task to run every `dt` interval.

But sometimes, I do want to force the task to be executed immediately. After the task has executed, I want the schedule to go back to normal. (ie., some `dt` amount of time after this 'forced' execution, the task should be executed again).

Is it possible to do that with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`? Could you show me how? Some simple example would be great!

I suppose one could do this by simply shutting down the schedule, executing the task manually, and calling `scheduleAtFixedRate` again, but I'm wondering if that's good practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question. Maybe you could call `cancel()` on the `ScheduledFuture<T>` that you received from calling `scheduledAtFixedRate()`, submit the task manually using `submit()`, and then reschedule your fixed rate task again when that `Future` comes back? You would have to check that the task isn't already running I suppose.

Some pseudocode...

```
ScheduledFuture<Thingy> sf = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, etc...);
sf.cancel();
final Future<Thingy> f = executor.submit(myTask);
f.get();
sf = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, etc...);
```

I've never done it, it's an interesting question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I kind of sort of thought of something like that, but I'm wondering that'd be a good practice. Is there any other pitch-fall I should watch out for?

Answer (score -1):

For a one shot execution use

```
ScheduledFuture<Thingy> sf = executor.schedule(myTask, 0, SECONDS);
```

This will execute `myTask` once and immediate but won't stop executing the tasks scheduled before with an interval. Is that really a problem?

Comment: Hm,... wouldn't give you something error like "task" already scheduled?

Comment: Why? The task (Runnable or Callable instance) is wrapped and scheduled. No executor will check for existence, you can submit one task as often as you like.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't mention it, but if I just blindly submit the task, there would be a chance that the two executions would be happening concurrently I do not wish that to happen. This is why I would like to  'force' the task to execute immediately, as opposed to submitting a new task.